# Tracing the sequence of hits/urls for users who have reached a certain goal

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, statistics, analytics, universal-analytics

I have a question Project Owner want me to find answer for.

I have a web-site. Some user visits web-site and navigates between pages, for instance some urls **{url_1, url_5, url_2, url_67, url_4}**. At the end of the sequence of this url navigation he implements some action, for instance "register button click" **{e1}**.

The task is to find ready-to-use from-the-box tool that allows:

1. To track all users and their hits actions across the web-site
2. To filter the users who have reached certain goal (e1)
3. To view the full stack of user hits for each user who have reached certain goal {e1}

For instance
“Goal 28415 ‘register button click’ (2):

1. 10.10.2013 10:56 AM 
   main.html > about_us.html > contacts.html > free_trial.html > *[Goal28415]*
2. 12.10.2013 13:16 PM 
    main.html > register.html > *[Goal28415]*

If Univeral Analytics allows so, please can you send me some links to a proper techniques?

Muchos Gracias.

Answer (score 0):

You can create user defined segments of the sequence type (via Segments->Add Segment->New and then select the sequence tab).

You can specify multiple steps plus select if the steps have to be executed immediately one after and other or if other steps in between are allowed.

You can start with your urls (page equals /myurl) and have a goal completion as the last step.